# nginx deny download and hotlinking images

Tags: nginx, windows-server-2012-r2

I am using `Nginx 1.8` on `Windows Server 2012 R2`. I am publishing realtime stock charting software snaps on the website. I use only basic `html`.
My goal is to stop hotlinking on images as well stop downloading them also.
I have tried `IIS` as well `Apache` couldn't stop hotlinking.
I have tried below code to stop hotlinking and got success.

```
location ~ .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ {
     valid_referers blocked example.com www.example.com;
     if ($invalid_referer) {
        rewrite (.*)\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ http://abc.example.com/banned-stamp-clipart.png;
    }
}
location /html/images/ {

  ## drop rest of the world
  deny    all;
}
```

But how to stop to download image from download managers such as IDM, with path for example `http://www.example.com/images/abc.png`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot prevent download of images because to show them in browser they need to be downloaded, if user decides to download - he/she will do it anyway, or just take a screenshot.

You can only make this harder. For example - make use of `X-Accel-Redirect` with server-side script that issues one-time tokens for image viewing, that are generated on html hit and expire when image is downloaded by browser (also checking referer there).

Images can be split into several parts, so that it is even harder to use 'as-is' (but also harder for youself to handle)

Also they can be fetched from browser cache, you may try adding no-cache headers, but it does not look as a good idea.